# Querying dependencies: Objects on which a view depends

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find out how to script referencing entities for a view.

To find objects that depend on I'm using the following script:

```
 SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
 referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
 FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.my_view', 'OBJECT');
 GO
```

However, what I'm trying to find out is: objects on which my view depends.

Through SQL Management Studio I can find them in the UI with the option on the picture below.

[image]

Is it possible to get  to this data through a script?

Comment: [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Yes, that's it! If you want you can post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite to `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` is [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), which works identically to the former function, just the other way round; it gives objects that object depends on, not objects that depend on it. So you would literally just replace the function name:

```sql
SELECT referencing_schema_name,
       referencing_entity_name,
       referencing_id,
       referencing_class_desc,
       is_caller_dependent
 FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.my_view', 'OBJECT');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities