# Get with T-SQL all the objects that a view depends on

Tags: sql-server

I need to get with T-SQL all the objects that a view depends on. I have been trying with some examples that are in this forum and modified by me for example in [Querying dependencies: Objects on which a view depends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72405294/querying-dependencies-objects-on-which-a-view-depends) using `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` but I did not get the results that can be seen in the attached image that is obtained from the "view dependencies" option in SSMS because function are not showed ; marked with a red square are the tables that are not necessary to show. Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: So you are trying to find objects that *VISTA_ORDEN_CARGA_TIEMPOS* depends on? As in, tables, views, and functions that are used within this view? You are on the right track, [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql) will show you the related objects, but you will need to create a recursive query.

Comment: What does `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` show? I've had better luck with that than `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` and `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` personally.

Comment: thanks @Ben, i'll try  `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`